# How to properly match newline with zsh regex?

Tags: command-line, git, regex, zsh

for my prompt i am trying to parse the current git branch out of the resulting text of the `git status` command. 
For example, it returns:

```
On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So in my prompt defining script for zsh i have:

```
git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null)"
$git_status =~ "^On branch (.*)$"
branch=$match[1]
```

But when i echo the `$branch`-Variable, i get:

```
master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

So, why is the `$` control sequence in the regular expression not matching with the newline after the branch name, and why is the match expanding over both lines?

Answer (score 1):

By using grep before you can work on one line

```
git_status="$(git status 2> /dev/null | grep 'On branch')"
[[ $git_status =~ "^On branch (.*)$" ]]
echo $match[1]
```

> $ zsh test.sh
>
> master

I didn't manage to get the same results with the multi-lines, if someone find a solution, I would be interest to see it.

*Tested with zsh 5.3*

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
[[ $git_status =~ "anch ([[:graph:]]*)" ]]
```

or

```
[[ $git_status =~ "anch ([[:print:]]*)" ]]
```

`[[:graph:]]*` will match a word
(i.e., everything up to the first space, tab, or newline);
`[[:print:]]*` will match the rest of the line
(i.e., everything up to a newline).

And of course you can say `^On branch` if you want to;
my point is that you don’t have to, if you’re reasonably confident
that the `$git_status` will be something like what you expect. 
*Do **not*** say **`$`** at the end of the regex.